# Run "traditional" unit test in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, nightwatch.js

I have a couple of utility functions, like validateEmail(email) that I would like to test directly, that is, without going through the UI.  Is that possible through [Nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/)?  I have all my UI testing in Nightwatch, and would like to stick with a single toolset for all my testing.
And yes, I "get it" that most testing can (and perhaps should) be at the "public" level.  But for completeness I also like to directly test some internal utility functions with every conceivable input.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is test individual units of code: unit testing. Nightwatch is for end-to-end and user interaction testing through browser automation. You can hack around it and expose your utility functions in a way that allows Nightwatch to get references it them but it's not the right tool for the job. Look into unit testing libraries like [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io) or [Mocha](http://mochajs.org).

Comment: Nightwatch is fine for UnitTesting

Comment: @SuperUberDuper how do you figure?

Answer (score 0):

Nightwatch now explicitly supports running this sort of test - note the `@unittest` annotation in the example below.
But, for some reason, this feature seem to be available on their site anymore.

An example:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const testScript = require('../../Scripts/unitTestScript');

const dataProvider = [
  {input: 'value_1', expected: 'value_1Test'},
  {input: 'value_2', expected: 'value_2Test'},
  {input: 'value_3', expected: 'value_3Test'},
];

module.exports = {
  '@tags': ['unit_test'],
  '@unitTest' : true,
  'example unit test' : function (done) {
    dataProvider.forEach(function (values) {
      assert.strictEqual(testScript.testMethod(values.input), values.expected);
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      done();
    }, 10);
  }
};
```

(from https://www.drupal.org/docs/automated-testing/javascript-testing-using-nightwatch#s-writing-unit-tests-in-nightwatch)